# Graph shortest path algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path

[image]

The input will be

8 // the numbers of block

1 4 // block A: from 1 to 3

8 11

5 7

3 6

9 13

2 6

5 9

8 14 // block H from 8 to 13

The question is to compute the minimum steps to move from the 1st block to the last block, which means, from A to H. You can move right or left on the same block, and you can jump straight to another block if they overlap on the number line, for example, you can jump from A to D or F, you can jump from C to D, or F, or G.

Here, the answer is 3. A -> D -> G -> H (or A -> F -> G -> F)

How can I solve this problem?
Please, thanks!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert your input to a graph.  Each "block" is a vertex.  Add edge between two vertices if they overlap on the number line.
2. Use the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path.